# Simple Variance approximation I don't get

Tags: probability, statistics

I have

$$ \log(\lambda_j -1) = c + \alpha_{j-1} $$

From here I know

$$ \lambda_j -1 = \exp(c+\alpha_{j-1})  $$

Then, they say

$$  Var(\hat \lambda_j)\approx\ Var(\hat \lambda_j - 1) \approx \exp(\hat c + \hat \alpha_{j-1})^2 Var(\hat c + \hat \alpha_{j-1})$$

$\hat c, \hat \lambda_j, \hat \alpha_{j-1}$ are estimators for $c, \lambda_j, \alpha_{j-1}$, respectively.

I don't get the last step (approximation). Anyone has any insight?

Thank you.

Comment: I have edited your last step. clearly Var(lambda)is approximate of Var(lambda-1) since lambda is not equal to lambda

Comment: Sinca lamda-1=exp(c+alpha) so var(lambd) is approximate of var(lambda-1)

Comment: Do you have Var(lambda) . I mean is it given

Comment: There is equality in my source. You have $\lambda_1$ and then you recursively proceed

Comment: And do you have Var(lamda_1) given

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how this matters. + Editing is not ok, there should be $Var(\hat \lambda_j) = Var(\hat \lambda_{j}-1)$

Comment: All right, editing could be not ok. so What is Var(lamda_i)

Comment: 0, since $\lambda_1$ is given. Why does it matter?

Comment: @SA-255525: variance is location invariant so $Var(X)=Var(X-k)$ for any constant $k$